# Pipes doesn't work in WinApi on Windows 7 but works on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-10

I made a server and a client in winapi.

Client sends an number and a base and the server returns the number in that base.
[image: Windows7 error]
My problem that it works in Windows 10, but it doesn't work in Windows 7 and I don't understand why. Some help?

Client:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

#define BUFFSIZE 512
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    LPDWORD bytesRead = 0;
    char res[50];
    int num, base;

    LPCTSTR Roura = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\pipeline");
    HANDLE h = CreateFile(Roura, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);


    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            res[i] = 0;
        }
        printf("Number: ");
        cin >> num;
        WriteFile(h, &num, sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);
        if (num == 0) {
            CloseHandle(h);
            return 0;
        }
        printf("Base: ");
        cin >> base;
        WriteFile(h, &base, sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);
        ReadFile(h, res, BUFFSIZE, bytesRead, NULL);
        cout << res << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define BUFFSIZE 512
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int num, base;
    LPDWORD bytesRead = 0;
    char result[50];
    char end[] = {"\0"};

    LPCTSTR Roura = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\pipeline");

    HANDLE h = CreateNamedPipe(Roura, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, BUFFSIZE, BUFFSIZE, 0, NULL);


    assert(h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    if (!ConnectNamedPipe(h, NULL)) return -1;

    while (true) {
        ReadFile(h, &num, BUFFSIZE, bytesRead, NULL);
        if (num == 0) {
            CloseHandle(h);
            return 0;
        }
        ReadFile(h, &base, BUFFSIZE, bytesRead, NULL);
        _itoa(num, result, base);
        WriteFile(h, result, strlen(result), NULL, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is your [error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/winapi/2573/error-reporting-and-handling#t=201612112131423457057)?

Comment: Start by checking for errors. Is every `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` succeeding? You don't know. And if one fails, call `GetLastError` to find out why.

Comment: @CareyGregory I can't understand why it works in Windows10 and in Windows7 falls.

Comment: `ReadFile(h, &num, BUFFSIZE, bytesRead, NULL);` when `int num` and `#define BUFFSIZE 512` - nice

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu by checking the success or otherwise of each statement and finding the exact error when it does fail will help tell you why it works in Windows 10 but fails in Windows 7.

Comment: your usage of `ReadFile` complete wrong and cause stack corrupt

Comment: @RbMm How should I fix it?

Comment: `DWORD bytesRead; ReadFile(h, &num, sizeof(num), &bytesRead, NULL);`

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu - can advice - run this code under debugger, and not create 2 separate app, but one app with 2 threads - create separate thread for client and test self code under debugger in single process

Comment: Why aren't you checking for errors

Comment: @RbMm I create a project in Visual Studio and after that I added another one. I don't know how to run the server and the client in Visual Studio. I can Run only once.

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu - you must learn how debug self code. this is absolute mandatory. and I advice - not create 2 app/2 process. but single app with 2 threads - client and server

Comment: @RbMm I'm not good at thread. Actually I am noob.

Comment: Then slow down and learn some basics before moving forward. You must know how to check for errors and use the tools available to you before you start tackling things like named pipes, otherwise all you'll do is waste time and write crap code. The world is full of crap code. Don't add to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define BUFFSIZE 512
int num, base;
LPDWORD bytesRead = 0;
ReadFile(h, &num, BUFFSIZE, bytesRead, NULL);
```

this code complete of errors. need use

```
int num, base;
DWORD bytesRead;
ReadFile(h, &num, sizeof(num), &bytesRead, NULL);
```

instead. crash faster of all by `bytesRead== 0`

when

> If lpOverlapped is NULL, lpNumberOfBytesRead cannot be NULL.

however this true on win7, but on say win10 - system let have `lpNumberOfBytesRead == 0` - so no crash here

also this

```
WriteFile(h, &num, sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);
```

again - here already only 1 error compare `ReadFile` call

> If lpOverlapped is NULL, lpNumberOfBytesWritten cannot be NULL.

why ?

> that it works in Windows 10, but it doesn't work in Windows 7

this is because begin from win 8.1 (*if I not mistake*) code of `ReadFile`/`WriteFile` check `lpNumberOfBytes` parameter and if it `==0` not assign to it actual number of bytes read or written. but on windows 7 system not do this check and unconditionally write data by 0 address

Comment: It's still crashing!

Comment: (`WriteFile(h, &num, sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);`) I found out that after this WriteFails client crashes

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu - of course by same reason 3-th parameter is 0

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu - yes

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu - 4-th parameter (`lpNumberOfBytesWritten`) must be not 0. and if in function declaration `LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten` this not mean that you must declare `LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten` in self code - this is fundamental misunderstand

Comment: Thanks! I made changes in WriteFile and ReadFile and now i works. Thanks for help!